# Set-cookie header not saving cookies

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, cors, jersey-2.0, setcookie

I know this question has been asked many times, but as on the great majority the answer was to set "withCredential" header to true, and it did not work for me, I'm still looking for an understanding of what is happening.

I'm working on an Angular application, at the login, the server return a WebSession token, and a set-cookie header in the response. 
I'm able to see the set-cookie header in Chrome inspector:

But as I said in the title, the cookies are not saved...
I read that in XHR request the set-cookie header could be ignored, but I also read many other thread which said that the option withCredentials is supposed to solve the problem.

So I'm still a bit confuse about these behavior, I would like to understand the macanism rather to just copy/paste stackoverflow answer until this works.

In my request header I specifiy that I wanted WithCredentials : true, by using an angular http interceptor, I also specifiy the two other headers : 
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
 "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true',

```
request = request.clone({
    withCredentials: true,
    setHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.webSessionToken}`,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": 'true',
    }
  });
```

On server side, I ended up adding a CORS filter with jersey to configure response headers :

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request,
                   ContainerResponseContext response) throws IOException {
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override");
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
}
```

Is there something that I forgot ?

EDIT :

An other strange behaviour I noticed :  when I logout (clean the storage to get rid of the websession token) and log in again, the cookies are sent in the authentication request, with the value get from the previous attempt, but still not showing up in the cookie tab in chrome:

[Authentication response with set cookie header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hWla.png)

[Authentication log in and logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZYLn.png)

[Cookie tab in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aFwG.png)

Comment: Remove `Access-Control-Allow-*****` from your angular code, these are server side headers and might end up causing more CORS issues since these headers are not allowed in request headers. Maybe also specify cookie path

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I remove the two header in request, but te cookies are still not set.

Comment: What do you mean by specify cookie path ?

Comment: You can set a Path when you set a cookie. If you don't, the cookie will only work for the url for which it was set. Can you add a screnshot of your cookies: in chrome, open dev console, go to applications tab and open up cookies for the current site on the left tab

Comment: Hi @David, thank you for your help, you were right, there was no path in my set-cookie header, so I guess the cookies were only accessible on the current page when the response set cookies, that is to say the login page.
Adding "path=/" in the set-cookie response header solved my issue.
Though I'm still surprise I couldn't see the cookie even on the login page

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the path for your cookie (`/` will work everywhere) when you set it server side. If not, the browser will consider that the cookie only apply to the path for whiwh it was set.

So if the cookie was wet when calling `http://api.com/login`, then the cookie will only be included in subsequent requests when calling  `http://api.com/login*` or `http://api.com/login/something`

**Note**

You need to remove `Access-Control-Allow-*****` headers from your angular code.

These are server side headers and might end up causing more CORS issues since these headers are not allowed in the list provided by `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` on your backend.